# IOS8 UISearchController display searchbar directly

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to display a simple search screen for my iphone app using a UISearchController.
I used a **UITableViewController** and a **UISearchController** that I embedded inside a **UINavigationController**

- This get me the following screen (**state 1**)

[image: searchcontroller with navigation bar]

- When user click on the search field I get the screen below (**state 2**): 
  The search bar display nicely at the top of the screen below the status bar.

[image: searchcontroller activated]

What I want to do is to get **state 2** straight away without going to **state 1**

I tried to add this code

```
presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but it either does not show the searchbar if animated is false or display it as I want but after an unnecessary transition that temporaryly shows the navigation bar

Comment: You question makes no sense. _You_ are the one who put the search field as the header view of the table view to begin with (state 1). If that is not what you wanted, why did you do it? If you wanted the search field to live in the navigation bar, why didn't you put it in the navigation bar instead?

Answer (score 7):

Ok I just found how to do it reading this answer [UISearchController in a UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417591/uisearchcontroller-in-a-uiviewcontroller)

I just need to add the searchbar like this to get the desired effect

```
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    // tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
```