# Using UIsearchController in UIViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a UIViewController (not UITableViewController) which has UISearchBar

When the user clicks on the search bar, i want only one row to appear as a suggestion (e.g Go to all Hospitals)

I tried to find examples of using UISearchConteroller but most of them use it for searching a table view

in this link, The answer refers to a UISearchDisplayController which is deprecated in iOS 8

[UISearchController in a UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417591/uisearchcontroller-in-a-uiviewcontroller)

How can I use UISearchController in regular view just to show one row? and when the user clicks this row, there will be an action

Thanks a lot

Comment: You will need to have a UITableView in your View Controller as well. THen in the delegate methods of the search bar, perform your actions to show the one line in your UITableView

Comment: @ByronCoetsee Thanks a lot